# Decorator pattern log each before and after

Tags: python, visitor-pattern

I want to log each iteration of my text changes nevertheless not sure what should be the proper way of doing that. See below. The first test is `GeeksforGeeks` and last one will be `<i><u><b>GeeksforGeeks</b></u></i>`. I want to print text changes on each iteration. I know i can do it like this to see each iteration by adding `LoggingWrapper` before every other wrapper like this:

```
gfg = LoggerWrapper(ItalicWrapper(LoggerWrapper(
        UnderlineWrapper(LoggerWrapper(BoldWrapper(LoggerWrapper(start)))))))
```

So then i see what i want to see:

```
LOG: GeeksforGeeks
LOG: <b>GeeksforGeeks</b>
LOG: <u><b>GeeksforGeeks</b></u>
LOG: <i><u><b>GeeksforGeeks</b></u></i>
```

**But i am not sure either is it fine approach or should i do this differently? Ya, this way i can decide on which step i want to see the log right? Is it right way or?**

My code:

```
class WrittenText:

    """Represents a Written text """

    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def render(self):
        return self._text


class UnderlineWrapper(WrittenText):

    """Wraps a tag in <u>"""

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def render(self):
        return "<u>{}</u>".format(self._wrapped.render())


class ItalicWrapper(WrittenText):

    """Wraps a tag in <i>"""

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def render(self):
        return "<i>{}</i>".format(self._wrapped.render())


class BoldWrapper(WrittenText):

    """Wraps a tag in <b>"""

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def render(self):
        return "<b>{}</b>".format(self._wrapped.render())


class LoggerWrapper(WrittenText):

    """Makes log"""

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def render(self):
        result = self._wrapped.render()
        print("LOG: " + result)
        return result


""" main method """

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = WrittenText("GeeksforGeeks")
    gfg = LoggerWrapper(ItalicWrapper(
        UnderlineWrapper(BoldWrapper(LoggerWrapper(start)))))

    gfg.render()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through a sequence of wrappers to be applied to the text, and wrap each wrapper call with `LoggerWrapper`:

```
gfg = 'GeeksforGeeks'

for wrapper in WrittenText, BoldWrapper, UnderlineWrapper, ItalicWrapper:
    gfg = LoggerWrapper(wrapper(gfg))

gfg.render()
```

Comment: great example. What about my example. Is it pretty fine as well to add ```LoggerWrapper``` the way i do?

Comment: IMHO the way you apply `LoggerWrapper` to every wrapper call looks too repetitive, which is precisely why I converted it to a loop in my answer.

Comment: i see but technically its fine besides repetitive?

Comment: Yes it's fine otherwise. It's just that I personally prefer adhering to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). That's all.

Comment: so simply speaking i am adding logger at the point i need thats it, and its fine with regards to this pattern? Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are using it perfectly right.

And I think of an alternative, just for discussion, I am using functional programming:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    italic_func = lambda x: "<i>{}</i>".format(x)
    bold_func = lambda x: "<b>{}</b>".format(x)
    underline_func = lambda x: "<u>{}</u>".format(x)
    log_func = lambda x: print("LOG: " + x)
    start = WrittenText("GeeksforGeeks")
    result = log_func(underline_func(bold_func(italic_func(log_func(start.render())))))
```

@nin17  thanks for pointing that out, I guess use def instead.

```
def italic_func(x): return  f"<i>{x}</i>"
# other functions
```

And if you want to log before and after some function call, I think decorator of python is the solution

```
def MyLogger():
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("before LOG: " + str(args))
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("after LOG: " + result)
            return result
        return wrapper

    return decorator

class BoldWrapper(WrittenText):
    """Wraps a tag in <b>"""

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    @MyLogger()
    def render(self):
        return "<b>{}</b>".format(self._wrapped.render())
```

Comment: assigning a ```lambda```expression  to a variable is discouraged: [pep8 - Programming Recommendations](https://pep8.org/#programming-recommendations) also using [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) is preferred to ```.format()```